# python & c-c++ unit programme cause Segment

Tags: python, c++, c

when i write c++ extended model code for python by ctypes, everything is looking ok.
forever, in the end, python call c++ function and return PyObject * get a segment error, i guess is python gc relase c++ memory. i hope every friends can give me a good idea, thanks very very much

```py
LID = ctypes.CDLL('./lib/a.out')
LID.cutall_prx.argtypes = [c_char_p]
LID.cutall_prx.restype = py_object
res = LID.cutall_prx('abc')
print res
```

```cpp
extern "C" PyObject * cutall_prx(const char *content){
    PyObject *oplist = PyList_New(10 + 1); 
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        PyList_Append(oplist, PyInt_FromLong(j));
    }   
    return oplist;
}
```

where print res cause  "Segmentation fault"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Note: If len is greater than zero, the returned list object’s items are set to NULL. Thus you cannot [...] expose the object to Python code before setting all items to a real object with PyList_SetItem()."

You're handing Python a list of 11 NULL pointers followed by 10 Long objects instead of overwriting the NULL pointenrs with values.

Try using `PyList_SetItem` instead:

```
extern "C" PyObject * cutall_prx(const char *content){
    PyObject *oplist = PyList_New(10); 
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        PyList_SetItem(oplist, j, PyInt_FromLong(j));
    }   
    return oplist;
}
```